# Hello.c: In function ‘main’: Hello.c:13: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’?

Tags: c, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should main() return in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c)

Just started coding C about an hour ago, after a few months of basic java coding, and am encountering a problem compiling the basic hello world program.

Here is my code:

```
#include < stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("\nHello World\n");
}
```

and this is what i get back when i try to compile:

```
 Hello.c: In function ‘main’:
 Hello.c:13: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’
```

any help would be much apprecated, thanks!

Comment: Get a better book or tutorial: `void main` is incorrect - it should be `int main`. (Unfortunately there are some bad books on C out there which use `void main` and you will often see this perpetuated in code examples on the web).

Comment: @PaulR, one sensitive test for bad C/C++ books is that they use `void main()`. Much excellent material on C is at http://lysator.liu.se/c

Comment: @vonbrand: absolutely - all the Indian colleges seem to use ancient and badly written books which all use `void main`, but the problem is not just limited to India.

Answer (score 5):

The standard signatures for `main` are either

```
int main(void)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Your compiler is simply enforcing the standard.

Note that an implementation *may* support `void main()`, but it must be explicitly documented, otherwise the behavior is undefined.  Like dandan78 says, a *large* number of books and online references get this wrong.

Comment: thanks for this, any idea where i'd be able to find an accurate tutorial/beginners guide to C online? After looking through a couple  have realised a lot make this mistake.

Comment: @JoePerkins: I don't personally know of a good *online* tutorial or guide for beginners; all the ones I've seen are pretty wretched.  However, there is the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com), which is pretty good, and the latest language standard is available [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).  Neither is the greatest *learning* resource, but they at least don't lead you astray.

Comment: @JoePerkins buy a good book, you can find a list in the information page of the c tag here on SO.

Answer (score 4):

it should be

```
int main() {}
```

then you should `return 0` if the program is terminating correctly or any other number if there was an error. That's an Unix convention, so scripts can check if the program was terminated correctly or an error occurred.

Comment: The standard says `#include <stdlib.h>` .... `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` or `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`

Comment: What sandard says that?
Usually different values for the exit codes are used so that is possible to distinguish between errors.

Answer (score 2):

main-function in c has to return an int:

```
#include < stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("\nHello World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Regardless of which prototype you choose for `main()`, it's return value cannot be `void`. It has to be `int`. Many books and tutorials get this wrong and some compilers tend to complain while others do not.

Comment: The return type of `main` _could_ be `void` as well as anything else, it's implementation-defined whether a signature is valid or not, and its behavior could be unspecified.

Comment: @effeffe Sorry to revive post on an old question but C++ standard section 3.6.1.2 states "An implementation shall not predefine the
main function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall allow both of the following
definitions of main :
`int main() {/∗. . .∗/}`
and
`int main(int argc , char* argv[]) {/∗. . .∗/}`

Comment: @jodag this question is about C, not C++.

Comment: @effeffe Oops, I was reading the "possible duplicate" section and saw C/C++ so assumed it was pertaining to C++ as well. My bad.